# (React Native) android emulator is not showing more than 6 images

Tags: android, django, react-native

[image]

My back-end is fine. I tried many ways to fix this problem, but it still shows the same result.

Approach

1. added `android:largeHeap="true"` to the `AndroidMnifest.xml`
2. cropped the image
3. ..?

My FlatList:

```
<View style={{ flex:1 }}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.props.tops}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      numColumns={3}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing = {this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh = {()=>this._onRefresh()}
        />
      }
      onEndReachedThreshold={thresholdLength}
      onEndReached = {()=>{
        this._onEndReachedThreshold()
      }}
    />
  </View>
```

Comment: Try adding `removeClippedSubviews={true}` in your `Flatlist` or `ScrollView` that you're using

Comment: Uhm I don't have `removeClippedSubviews` on my FlatList. Let me post my FlatList.

Comment: @PritishVaidya is saying you should try **adding** the prop, so I'm not sure why your response is that you don't have it. Have you tried running this as a release build? I frequently experience issues with Android and images while in debug builds, specifically images will sometimes never load if the image is too large, but the probably never carries to production